# Как привести к правильному типу std::any

Tags: c++

как можно скастовать `std::any` в тип, который содержит в себе сам объект `any`. То есть, есть ли более элегантный способ чем этот :

```
    any a{ 1002; };

    if (a.type() == typeid(string))
        cout << any_cast<string>(a);
    else if (a.type() == typeid(int))
        cout << any_cast<int>(a);
   ...
```

Можно ли как-то сразу вывести на экран значение без куча `if'ов`

Comment: Никак нельзя. Только хранить вместе с `any` лямбду для его печати.

Comment: А если вам известен полный список возможных типов, то взять `variant`.

Comment: спасибо, это и правда недостаток `any`.

Comment: `vector<pair<any, type>> va{ {2ull, unsigned long long},{'w', char}};`  можно ли как-то вместе с `any` влепить тип, но не знаю как сделать

Comment: Вместо типа - храните указатель на функцию, (или лямюду, или указатель на интерфейс из нескольких функций,...), котрорую можно сделть и шаблонной.  Либо создайте глобальную коллекцию всех типов (и функций печати),  которые собираетесь хранить в any.